# i am building a tic tac toe game for a class. can someone look at my code and tell me what i am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I get the error on the event handler for this.css, for some reason i cant assign those images to the background of the cell.

thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var turn = 0;

  $("#cell11 , #cell12, #cell13, #cell21, #cell22, #cell23, #cell31, #cell32, #cell33 ")
    .click(
      function(){
        // alert("click");
        var cell = this;
          if(turn=== 0){

            cell.css("background", "url(images/o.png");
            turn = 1 ;

          }else{
            cell.css("background", "url(images/x.png");
            turn = 0;
          }
      }
    );

});
```

Comment: You're trying to set the background to `url(images/o.png` or `url(images/x.png`.  (Note the missing `)` on both.)

Comment: Probably you should replace "var cell = this;" with "var cell = $(this);".

Comment: You have the answer so far. Also, notice url( doesn't close parenthesis. But perhaps thats just a copy/paste typo

Comment: And to avoid that long line: $("#cell11 , #cell12, #cell13, #cell21, #cell22, #cell23, #cell31, #cell32, #cell33 ") better use a common selector for all those elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate the jQuery class on `this`:

```
var cell = $(this);
```

---

Also, fix the typo as mentioned [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644732/i-am-building-a-tic-tac-toe-game-for-a-class-can-someone-look-at-my-code-and-te/26644777#comment41895541_26644732):

```
if( turn === 0){
    cell.css("background", "url(images/o.png)");
    turn = 1 ;
}
else {
    cell.css("background", "url(images/x.png)");
    turn = 0;
}
```